# filter object Keys and add result in '|' seperated string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have an object as

```
const sourceObj = {
    'back': true,
    'submit': true,
    'firtsName': 'My First Name',
    'lastName': 'My Last Name',
    'isUSCitizen': true
}
```

Need to exclude back and submit keys and add other keys in the `|` seperated string as below

```
result : 'firstName|lastName|isUScitizen'
```

Tried using

```
const {back, submit, ...rest} = sourceObj;
Object.keys(rest);
```

This returns an array , how to proceed get `result` string?

Comment: Have you tried `rest.join('|')`?

Comment: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Keep in mind that object keys' order is not guaranteed.

Comment: You seem to mention a certain order needed below, which is in fact based on the order of user entry. This will require quite a different approach using code that tracks user input on each field. If the user entry order is not needed but the original order is needed, then it seems like you should just use the `form.elements` array-like collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the array.

```js
const sourceObj = {
    'back': true,
    'submit': true,
    'firtsName': 'My First Name',
    'lastName': 'My Last Name',
    'isUSCitizen': true
};

const {back, submit, ...rest} = sourceObj;

console.log(Object.keys(rest).join("|"));
```

Be aware that rest syntax in object literal destructuring is not yet official, but is very close, so browser support is limited.

Comment: This will return `'firstName|lastName|isUSCitizen'`, not the values needed. ES2017 added `Object.values()`, but you may not be able to depend on the order.

Comment: @SamR: The question is asking for the keys, not the values.

Comment: @NinaScholz: I'm using the syntax used in the question, which has limited browser support.

Comment: @spanky I have updated your snippet to use Babel to compile. If the edit is not required, please revert it

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `Object.keys()` is the solution, here. It drops the values, which is what you actually need, I presume. You need to extract specific values in a specific order. For this you could easily use `.map()`:

```
['firstName','lastName','isUScitizen'].map((key)=>rest[key]).join('|');
```

Additional questions:
Are there any other keys that might be in the object?
Could any of the keys be missing?

Comment: yes that could be the case... actually these are form fields, and i need to add them in the order they are filled by user within sourceObj.